# Compensate for standard deviation loss

Tags: fft, matlab, gaussian

I am not sure if this question will be a little off-topic on this forum, that I will give it a try anyway, since it implies signal process arguments.

By using `MATLAB`, I'm on my way to generate a *turbulent wind field*. This wind field is generally a *Gaussian process* with all the time series having **0 mean value** and **unitary standard deviation**. I will shortly introduce you to the problem:

1) Discretize the space in **Y-Z** plane in a certain number of points `Ny`, `Nz`;

2) Discretize the time scale (generally *600s*) with a proper time sample, `dt = 0.15`;

3) Calculate distance among points;

4) Generate only positive frequency vector `f = (0:length(t)/2-1)*df`;

5) Generate power spectra

$$ S_{ii}(f)=\frac{4\sigma_{ii}^{2}\left(L_{ii}/U\right)}{\left(1+6f\left(L_{ii}/U\right)\right)^{5/3}} $$
where
$$ ii = u,v,w\,\, (speed\,\,components\,in\,x\,y\,z\,direction)$$
$$ U = const $$
$$ L_{ii} = const $$

6) Generate coherence matix

$$ Coh_{u}=\exp\left(-12\sqrt{\left(\frac{f*dist}{U}\right)^{2}+\left(0.12\frac{dist}{U}\right)^{2}}\right) $$
$$ Coh_{v,w}= \exp\left(-12\, dist\,\frac{f}{U}\right) $$

7) Generate random numbers with 0 mean and 1 std

```
nn_u = complex(normrnd(0,1,size(H_u)),normrnd(0,1,size(H_u)));
nn_v = complex(normrnd(0,1,size(H_v)),normrnd(0,1,size(H_v)));
nn_w = complex(normrnd(0,1,size(H_w)),normrnd(0,1,size(H_w)));
```

8) Cholesky factorization of the Coherence matrix (retrieves lower triangular factor)

9) Generate time series

$$ U = [real(fft(Coh_{u}*nn_{u}))\,\,imag(fft(Coh_{u}*nn_{u}))] $$
$$ V = [real(fft(Coh_{v}*nn_{v}))\,\,imag(fft(Coh_{v}*nn_{v}))] $$
$$ W = [real(fft(Coh_{w}*nn_{w}))\,\,imag(fft(Coh_{w}*nn_{w}))] $$

Now, after this consistent theorethical introduction, **I can move towards the real matter**: when calculating the standard deviations for eac time series *(u,v,w components)*, they don't match the expected values
$$ \sigma_{u} = 1 $$
$$ \sigma_{v} = 0.8 $$
$$ \sigma_{w} = 0.5 $$
because of several reasons:

- space discretization introducing smoothing effects
- time sample period
- power spectrum only within a short frequency range

**Btw, I would like to, let's say, scale the time series in order they to be still Gaussian variables with zero mean and a standard deviation better approaching the expected values.**

Do you have any hint?